# how to obtain these trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, angle, pythagorean-triples

I have the following Figure and equations:

[image: Image of rotation angles]

$$
\rho = \arctan(\frac{Ax}{\sqrt{Ay^{2} + Az^{2}}}) \tag{1} 
$$

$$
\phi = \arctan(\frac{Ay}{\sqrt{Ax^{2} + Az^{2}}}) \tag{2}
$$

$$
\theta = \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{Ax^{2} + Ay^{2}}}{Az}) \tag{3}
$$

The body on the Figures is a tri-axial accelerometer sensor, which measures accelaration in meters/seconds².

The goal is to calculate the tilt of the following angles using acceleration values:

- ρ: angle of the X-axis relative to the ground (orange line);
- Φ: angle of the Y-axis relative to the ground (orange line);
- θ: angle of the Z-axis relative to the gravity (green line).

Could someone explain how to find equations 1,2 and 3 from the figure above?

Source of the equations and figure: https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/AN3461.pdf

There is another similar and more detailed source that uses the same equations, but I also could not understand how to find them: https://www.analog.com/en/app-notes/an-1057.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These equations don't make sense, could you check you haven't omitted something? Like a $\sin$, $\cos$, etc.

Comment: In the paper, all three formulas have an $\arctan$ function.

Answer (score 1):

In the following diagram, you can obtain the angle $\theta$ using the formula
$$
\theta = \arctan (o/a)\tag{1}
$$
where $o$ denotes the length of the side of the triangle **o**pposite $\theta$, and $a$ denotes the length of the site **a**djacent to $\theta$. You can calculate the length of the other side, called the **h**ypotenuse, using [Pythagoras's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), $h^2=o^2+a^2$, which becomes $h=\sqrt{o^2+a^2}$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still have a question.

If I apply this logic to find ρ, for example, looking at Figure B:  https://imgur.com/pbr9nnk

wouldn't X be the hyphotenuse? If yes, how could it be opposite to ρ?

I am missing something in the way that I try to draw these triangles to try to find those equations but I still don't know how should I see the Figure.

Comment: @Matheus your question says that $\rho$ is the angle relative to the ground so I would have thought that it is the angle between the $x$ axis and the upward arrow.

Comment: Sorry, I still could not get it. Is the green line the upward arrow you are reffering to? Would you mind drawing for me so I could undarstand better? I still don't know how Ax wold be opposite to ρ and √Ay²+Az² adjacent to ρ to find Equation 1.  


Furthermore, to obtain √Ay²+Az² I believe that this would have to be the hyphotenuse of the triangle (because of Pythagora's theorem), but for Equation 1 to make sense, it should be adjacent to ρ, since ρ = arctan(o/a) and not ρ = arctan(o/hypotenuse).

Comment: @Matheus maybe try to edit your question or ask another question if you can't understand, it's pretty annoying when people start asking more questions in the comments.

Comment: No problem, I will create another question then. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Matheus good idea!