# Finding an orthonormal basis given its "angular distance" from the $x,y,z$ axes

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, orthogonal-matrices

I looking into the problem of finding solutions (there could be more than one) for the rotation matrix $R = [u_1, u_2, u_3] $ where $u_1, u_2, u_3$ are unit vectors and mutually orthogonal, and that in addition saisfies the following

$$ u_1 \cdot i = \alpha \\u_2 \cdot j = \beta \\u_3 \cdot k = \gamma $$

where $i,j,k$ are the unit vectors along the $x,y,z$ axes respectively.

In other words, I would like to find all the off-diagonal entries of orthogonal matrices $R$ whose diagonal entries are known.

I am looking for either a closed-form solution (this would be preferrable), or an algorithm for finding the solutions numerically.

The problem is inspired by [this recent MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492268/finding-trigonometric-equations-from-3d-figure)

Comment: You said it yourself, $\{u_i\}$ are unit vectors and mutually orthogonal. This gives you $6$ equations. Knowing the diagonal elements reduces the number of unknowns from $9$ to $6$. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: But these are quadratic equations, how can you solve 6 quadratic equations in 6 unknowns ?

Comment: Well, not easily. You can plug it in software and you won't get something nice. That brings us to the issue of your question, what did you try and what result do you expect to find? Why do you want to know in the first place? Is there any reason why you would expect something nice in full generality? One approach that could possibly lessen the suffering a bit is to do appropriate trigonometric substitutions using the fact that these are 3D unit vectors with a coordinate fixed, so a single angle is enough to parametrize it.

Comment: I am not expecting something nice and in closed form, but at least an algorithm to find all the possible solutions, numerically.

Comment: I'd recommend that you edit your question with those details, it might attract more attention.

Comment: Thanks @Ennar, I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation matrix for a unit quaternion $\mathbf q = q_r + q_i\mathbf i + q_j\mathbf j + q_k\mathbf k$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 - 2(q_j^2 + q_k^2) & 2(q_iq_j - q_kq_r) & 2(q_iq_k + q_jq_r) \\
2(q_iq_j + q_kq_r) & 1 - 2(q_i^2 + q_k^2) & 2(q_jq_k - q_iq_r) \\
2(q_iq_k - q_jq_r) & 2(q_jq_k + q_iq_r) & 1 - 2(q_i^2 + q_j^2)
\end{bmatrix}.$$

This gives us four linear equations in $q_r^2, q_i^2, q_j^2, q_k^2$:

\begin{gather*}
q_r^2 + q_i^2 + q_j^2 + q_k^2 = 1, \\
1 - 2(q_j^2 + q_k^2) = α, \quad
1 - 2(q_i^2 + q_k^2) = β, \quad
1 - 2(q_i^2 + q_j^2) = γ,
\end{gather*}

which are easily solved:

\begin{gather*}
q_r = ±\frac{\sqrt{1 + α + β + γ}}{2}, \quad
q_i = ±\frac{\sqrt{1 + α - β - γ}}{2}, \\
q_j = ±\frac{\sqrt{1 - α + β - γ}}{2}, \quad
q_k = ±\frac{\sqrt{1 - α - β + γ}}{2}.
\end{gather*}

This yields up to 8 different rotation matrices (since $-\mathbf q$ yields the same matrix as $\mathbf q$).

There are also up to 8 orthogonal matrices that are rotary reflections rather than rotations, obtained as the negations of the rotation matrices for $-α, -β, -γ$.